# Custom attribute in B2C Signup page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have created custom attributes to my Azure B2C directory, and would now like to do a custom signup page but cannot figure out how to "map" the ui element to the custom attribute, please help.

From the example my guess is I need to use "`extension_`" suffixed witht the field name in the element id? The documentation is thin in this area

```
<div class="attrEntry">
    <div class="helpText"></div>
    <label>Loyalty number</label>
    <input id="extension_MemNum" class="textInput" type="text" placeholder="Loyalty number"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="selfAssertedClient.showHelp('Membership number');" class="tiny">What is this?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want to style the signup page, there is only CSS to add.
The mapping is done automatically, edit the signup policy to include the new field. You can arrange the order of the fields by dragging and dropping. All fields are auto generated in the UI.
You can limit what values are entered in the signup/edit policy as well.

Go to `page UI customization` -> `local account signup`  -> `double click any of the attributes`
Now you can select a dropdown(or radio or chackbox) and limit what values are entered.

**Detailed steps:** 
Go to the signup policy (or the edit policy)
[image: b2c Sign Up policy]

Select Page UI customization and then Local Account sign up
[image: b2c Page ui customization]

Select the attribute and edit it (select dropdown, or radiobutton)
[image: edit b2c attribute]

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization/

If you look at the generated page, you will see all the generated fields, if you want to customize everything.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added fields in the policies. One of the fields need a distinct list of options to choose form so a select is an obvious choice. My question is how do I tell B2C to store the selected value in that field?

Comment: Updated my answer with this info, creating a dropdown is hidden under page ui customization

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have looked at the sample code in that link but that still does not tell me how to map an html element to a B2C attribute. I also cannot find the 'page UI customisation' you refer to, is that in the old portal or the new one?

Comment: All these B2C actions are in the new portal, see the screenshots in my updated answer

Comment: Wow, thanks for being so patient with me and giving such a good answer, which I could up vote it more than once

Comment: @ErikOppedijk a little more on your comment, " You can arrange the order of the fields." It is not obvious that while in the Portal screen you can "drag-n-drop" the fields to rearrange the order.